# MySQL index to the left?

Tags: mysql

I've read that MySQL indexes to the left, so if I create an index across two columns `field1`,`field2` I can do:

```
 SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE `field1` = 'x' AND `field2` = 'y';
```

and

```
 SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE `field1` = 'x';
```

and both would be fine? I'm asking because sometimes it will be querying by both columns and sometimes just by the first. Or would it be better to have two different indices for both scenarios?

Comment: link for you http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the two-column index can benefit both queries.  No need to create two indexes.

In fact, the tool [pt-duplicate-key-checker](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-duplicate-key-checker.html) would report the single-column index as redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Simontemplar, you're right. Both queries are right. As long as you are not running:

```
 SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE `field2` = 'y' AND `field1` = 'x';
```

or

```
 SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE `field2` = 'y';
```

Keeping a composed index should not be a problem.

Comment: MySQL knows how to use the index in the first example above.  The optimizer knows that `AND` is commutative.  :-)

Comment: tks Bill for the complement!